# APP_NAME wants additional access to your Google account

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin

What is throwing me off here is the keyword *additional*. Users are seeing this screen every time they sign in with Google. Shouldn't they only see it once (the first time)?

[image]

I'm using the [Google 3P Authorization JavaScript Library for websites](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference).

I followed [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#gis-popup-ux) in my implementation.

It just seems weird to me that the screen says "additional access" but then doesn't list any additional permission requests.

Anyone have any idea what could be causing this? Or is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I have the same problem with an unverified app. Have you tried a Google verified app?

Comment: Same here, with a verified app (with 4 services already added)

Answer (score 0):

I think that is caused by the selected scopes. An scope is the set of resources and operations that an access token permits.
Reading the documentation you followed, it has been selected an scope to be able to read the calendar:

```
function initClient() {
    client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      **scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',**
```

But the default scope is email (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email) and profile (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile) so this is why that screen appears and asks for additional access.
Try to change the scope, please.

More information about google OAuth scopes: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#oauth2

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to add `include_granted_scopes: false` to `initCodeClient`

```
client = google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient({
      include_granted_scopes: false,
      client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
      ....
```

The "needs additional access" screen went away after I deployed this change.

I guess this makes sense since the flag controls whether the app will `request access to additional scopes`. The [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/reference/js-reference#CodeClientConfig) say

> Optional, defaults to true. Enables applications to use incremental authorization to request access to additional scopes in context. If you set this parameter's value to false and the authorization request is granted, then the new access token will only cover any scopes to which the scope requested in this CodeClientConfig.